# Radon–Nikodym Derivatives

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two bounded measures on a measurable space $(\Omega, A)$. Show that there is a bounded measure $\lambda$ on $(\Omega, A)$ and two non-negative, bounded, $A$-measurable functions $f : \Omega → \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \Omega → \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu = f · \lambda$ and $\nu = g · \lambda$.

I honestly don't know how to start proving this. A hint would be appreciated. Do $f$ and $g$ have to be unique?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mu=f\cdot\lambda$? That $\mu(E) = \int_E f\ \mathsf d\lambda$ for $E\in A$?

Comment: Yes, I mean the measure $f \cdot \lambda (E) = \int_{E} f \; d\lambda$.

Comment: Okay, normally I see the notation $\mathsf d\mu = f\mathsf d\lambda$ for that, so I was confused.

Comment: No worries, thanks for helping me clarify. I've only ever seen the one notation.

Comment: BTW, I wonder how many people noticed that the question's title uses an en-dash rather than a hyphen in "Radon–Nikodym"?  The en-dash is the form considered correct by Wikipedia's style manual. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4):

You can take $\lambda$ to be $\mu+\nu$.  It is easy to show that  both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to that, and then if the Radon–Nikodym theorem is available to you, then that does the rest.